# How to deal with the ground node in circuit graph and the gains of dependent sources?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ground, current-source, gain, graph

in this circuit I am asked to find the gains of both dependent current and voltage sources. I've drawn the circuit graph and done the analysis that I had supposed. But I am not sure about whether there should be four or five nodes in the graph. I supposed that there are just four nodes since the currents before and after the ground (from right to left) are the some so the difference in voltage also should be the same. But after that I had i3 in a negative value! If this is correct should the gain g be positive or negative?[image]

Comment: There is a schematic editor here, with the ability to display your circuit. Please use it to clarify the situation. It's hard to read your photo.

Answer (score 0):

I see there also only 3 nodes.

The picture is hard to read but if the calculation is right the minus means only that your first intention of writing down the direction of our graph for i3 was in the wrong direction.

If you change this you will get a positive gain g.

Its just a matter of drawing your graphs.

Comment: I wrote its direction as described in the circuit I  changed nothing in that.